# A failure was encountered while passing parameters using 'meta'

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to learn the usage of "meta" in scrapy framework. The website I'm trying to scrape is "http://quotes.toscrape.com/", my requirement is to scrape the first page's "quote" , "author" and author's birth date, where the first two are on the first level page and the author'birth date is on the second level page, I need Use "meta" to convey both the quote and the author.

Below is my code, and my output command, it runs as "nothing", I don't know what's causing it, so I'm asking for help here.

```py
# item.py

class ShuoItem(scrapy.Item):
    quote = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    more = scrapy.Field()
```

```py
# shuo.py

import re
import scrapy
from ..items import ShuoItem
from scrapy import Request


class ShuoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shuo'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        blocks = response.xpath(
            "//div[@class='container']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-md-8']/div[@class='quote']").extract()
        pattern1 = re.compile(r'<span class="text" itemprop="text">(.*?)</span>')
        pattern2 = re.compile(r'<small class="author" itemprop="author">(.*?)</small>')
        pattern3 = re.compile(r'<a href="(.*?)">')
        for block in blocks:
            quote = pattern1.findall(block)[0]
            author = pattern2.findall(block)[0]
            mo = pattern3.findall(block)[0]
            mo = response.urljoin(mo)
            yield Request(url=mo, meta={'k1': quote, 'k2': author}, callback=self.parse_date())

    def parse_date(self, response):
        item = ShuoItem()
        item['quote'] = response.meta['k1']
        item['author'] = response.meta['k2']
        item['more'] = response.xpath("/html/body/div[@class='container']/div[@class='author-details']/p[1]/span[@class='author-born-date']/text()").extract_first()

        yield item
```

```py
# my command

scrapy crawl shuo -o boo.json -s FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING=utf-8
```

Comment: Try `callback=self.parse_date` - no instantiation (no brackets).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parenthesis in `callback=self.parse_date()`

```py
import re
import scrapy
from ..items import ShuoItem
from scrapy import Request


class ShuoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shuo'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        blocks = response.xpath(
            "//div[@class='container']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-md-8']/div[@class='quote']").extract()
        pattern1 = re.compile(r'<span class="text" itemprop="text">(.*?)</span>')
        pattern2 = re.compile(r'<small class="author" itemprop="author">(.*?)</small>')
        pattern3 = re.compile(r'<a href="(.*?)">')
        for block in blocks:
            quote = pattern1.findall(block)[0]
            author = pattern2.findall(block)[0]
            mo = pattern3.findall(block)[0]
            mo = response.urljoin(mo)
            yield Request(url=mo, meta={'k1': quote, 'k2': author}, callback=self.parse_date)

    def parse_date(self, response):
        item = ShuoItem()        
        item['quote'] = response.meta['k1']
        item['author'] = response.meta['k2']
        item['more'] = response.xpath("/html/body/div[@class='container']/div[@class='author-details']/p[1]/span[@class='author-born-date']/text()").extract_first()

        yield item
```

**Things that you can improve:**

1. Learn the basics of xapth, maybe find yourself a [Xpath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath) and lose the regex as it's really not necessary in this code. Also it will help you in the future in webpages that are more complicated, and your selectors will be a lot shorter and readable.
2. You can declare the item inside the for loop and just pass it to the callback instead of sending multiple values.
3. You can use [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs) instead of `meta`. I find it nicer to use...
4. Not a mistake, but read about [response.follow](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow), you can also use `urljoin` of course.

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import ShuoItem


class ShuoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shuo'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        blocks = response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]')

        for block in blocks:
            item = ShuoItem()
            item['quote'] = block.xpath('.//span[@class="text"]/text()').get()
            item['author'] = block.xpath('.//small[@class="author"]/text()').get()
            mo = block.xpath('.//a/@href').get()
            yield response.follow(url=mo, cb_kwargs={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_date)

    def parse_date(self, response, item):
        item['more'] = response.xpath('//span[@class="author-born-date"]/text()').get()
        yield item
```